# How to define closed union of alternatives

Tags: xml, xsd, saxon

I have an XML, which is loosely a "composite" of shapes that can contain other shapes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootShape>
    <SQUARE width="10" x="1" y="25">
        <contains>
            <TRIANGLE rotation="180" x="1" y="34">
                <contains>
                    <TRIANGLE rotation="180" x="221" y="34">
                        <contains/>
                    </TRIANGLE>
                    <SQUARE width="10" x="1" y="25">
                        <contains/>
                    </SQUARE>
                </contains>                        
            </TRIANGLE>
        </contains>
    </SQUARE>
</rootShape>
```

I have an xsd, which seeks to describe, constrain and ultimately be used in a schema aware XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="SQUARETYPE">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contains">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="SQUARE">
                            <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
                            <xs:alternative test="@kind='SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>                                
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
                    </xs:choice>                        
                </xs:complexType>                    
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FILLEDSQUARETYPE">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contains">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="SQUARE">
                            <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
                            <xs:alternative test="@kind='SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>                                
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
                    </xs:choice>                        
                </xs:complexType>                    
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="colour" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TRIANGLETYPE">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contains">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="SQUARE">
                                <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
                                <xs:alternative test="@kind='SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>                                
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
                        </xs:choice>                        
                    </xs:complexType>                    
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="rootShape">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="SQUARE">
                    <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
                    <xs:alternative test="@kind='SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>   
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
            </xs:choice>                        
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML validates against the XSLT, but I'm not sure why.

the crux being this definition of the union type of "FILLEDSQUARETYPE", "SQUARETYPE" and "TRIANGLETYPE"

```
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="SQUARE">
                    <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
                    <xs:alternative test="@kind='SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>   
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
            </xs:choice>
```

which seeks to infer a type to the element "SQUARE", based on some property of it.

yet my "SQUARE" elemnts do not contain a "kind" attribute, so dont inhabit either type.

So...I'm slightly confused, what type does it infer?

The choice construct imposes a set closure of the possibilities of elements, the alternative construct doesn't seem to do the same? I don't want an open definition, I want a closed one.

---

I did wonder if this would close it

```
<xs:element name="SQUARE">
    <xs:alternative test="@kind='FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>                                
    <xs:alternative type="SQUARETYPE"/>                                
</xs:element>
```

i.e. a square is either a FILLEDSQUARETYPE or if not it MUST be a SQUARETYPE, so then looking at the definition of this type, it must have a kind attribute, and if it doesnt, then thats an error?...but this is not what seems to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the alternatives is satisfied, then the type defaults to the type declared on the containing element declaration, which itself defaults to `xs:anyType`.

If you want validation to fail when the `@kind` is not one of those listed, then add an enumeration facet to constrain the value of `@kind`.

Comment: ooo, thats what I wondered, so I can't defined a closed set of alternatives? I can only close the underlying data? Can I default the type if it doesnt match? and then define a type I know isnt ever inhabited?

Comment: hmmm...I also don't think thats going to work, I'll try it, and update the question though

Comment: yeah that doesnt work, my SQUARE element doesnt contain any kind attribute at all, so the validation never knows that "kind" should exist to validate whats in it i.e. the problem isnt that the value of kind is wrong, the problem is that it doesnt exist at all.

Comment: I've updated my question with an even more simple version, where I would hope I am closing the set of alternatives, but I'm still not getting an error when I validate the xml.

Comment: see my answer, I've done it by introducing a "top" type, but frankly, I don't like it, I'd much prefer "alternative" to be more like a "match" pattern, and drop through until it finds something, and then I can then decide to catch everything...i.e. close the alternatives.

Comment: If the @kind attribute is mandatory, then declare it as mandatory!. But if you prefer then you can also add a final alternative which declares the type as `xs:error`, a type that nothing will ever conform to.

Comment: I would have to declare it mandatory on the default type defined in the element (the parent of the alternatives?)....but maybe I should look at xs:error.

Comment: I'll take a look at xs:error, that looks much better than my solution, the "kind" thing actually may not be mandatory....i.e. there may not be nice intersection type between the alternatives...and if there way I'd have to try to calculate it, which I don't want to do (in fact thats why I introduced "Top" because it was the obvious intersection type).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a commment from Michael Kay

the solution is

```
<xs:element name="SQUARE">
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
</xs:element>
```

Which seems to work for me.